# How to scrape elements of nested drop-down with Rselenium?

Tags: r, web-scraping, rselenium

I'm trying to scrape [this](https://www.saglamaile.az/analyzes/) website with Rselenium. On the left side of website, there are "nested" drop-down lists. For each list I only can take [xpath](https://i.stack.imgur.com/twh2S.png) of elements.

So I tried using `for loop` for first drop-down list as below:

> ```
> for (i in 1:6) {
>   q <- enexpr(i)
>   xpath_1 <- glue("/html/body/div[1]/div[3]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[{enexpr(q)}]/h2/a")
>   driver$findElement("xpath", xpath_1)$clickElement()
>   result[i,1] <- driver$findElement("xpath", xpath_1)$getElementText()
> ```

That gives me first 6 drop-down elements as dataframe. However for second nested drop-down I need to connect them in result dataframe:

> ```
> for (i in 1:6) {
>   q <- enexpr(i)
>   xpath_1 <- glue("/html/body/div[1]/div[3]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[{enexpr(q)}]/h2/a")
>   driver$findElement("xpath", xpath_1)$clickElement()
>   result[i,1] <- driver$findElement("xpath", xpath_1)$getElementText()
>   
>   for (a in 1:17) {
>     b <- enexpr(a)
>     xpath_2 <- glue("/html/body/div[1]/div[3]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div/article[{enexpr(b)}]/h3/a")
>     driver$findElement("xpath", xpath_2)$clickElement()
>     result[a,2] <- driver$findElement("xpath", xpath_2)$getElementText() 
>   } 
> }
> ```

Result is like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CTyjR.png). Only the elements of the first drop-down are given in column 2, although other drop-downs have the same xpath as the sub-elements. My aim is to get the table with the related drop-down elements, as below:

```
Col1      Col2
 a         1 
 a         2
 a         3
 b         8
 b         9
```

Can anyone help me figure out what I can do?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a partial answer,

To get the `parents` text we can do

```
remDr$getPageSource()[[1]] %>% read_html() %>% 
  html_nodes('body > div.main_wrapper > div.inner_content.long > div > div.analiz_wrapper > div.analiz_left.css_scroll > div:nth-child(n)') %>%
   html_nodes('h2') %>% html_text()
[1] "Laborator müayinələr"   "Funksional müayinələr"  "Poliklinik müayinələr"  "Həkim konsultasiyaları" "Hədiyyə kartları"       "Endirimli müayinələr"
```

To get the text of `parents > child` we can do, (This fetches you text of only first parent, you need to write a loop to get text from other parents)

```
remDr$getPageSource()[[1]] %>% read_html() %>% 
  html_nodes('body > div.main_wrapper > div.inner_content.long > div > div.analiz_wrapper > div.analiz_left.css_scroll > div:nth-child(1) > div > article:nth-child(n)') %>%
  html_nodes('h3') %>% html_text()

 [1] "COVID-19 testi"                   "Qanın müayinəsi"                  "Sidiyin müayinəsi"                "Nəcisin müayinəsi"               
 [5] "Spermanın müayinəsi"              "Urogenital sıyrıntının müayinəsi" "Likvorun müayinəsi"               "Saçın müayinəsi"                 
 [9] "Abortiv materialın müayinəsi"     "Ana südünün müayinəsi"            "Plevral mayenin müayinəsi"        "Prostat vəzi şirəsinin müayinəsi"
[13] "Bəlğəmin müayinəsi"               "Bioptatın müayinəsi"              "Konyuktivadan sıyrıntı"           "Yaradan sıyrıntının müayinəsi"   
[17] "Digər biomateriallar"
```

Finally to get text from `parents > child > child` (It too gets text from first parent's second child, you need to write loop for others)

```
remDr$getPageSource()[[1]] %>% read_html() %>% 
  html_nodes('body > div.main_wrapper > div.inner_content.long > div > div.analiz_wrapper > div.analiz_left.css_scroll > div:nth-child(1) > div > article:nth-child(2) > div > ul > li:nth-child(n)') %>%
  html_text()
[1] "Hematoloji müayinələr"                 "Biokimyəvi müayinələr"                 "Hormonal müayinələr"                  
[4] "İmmunoloji müayinələr"                 "Allerqoloji müayinələr"                "İnfeksion xəstəliklərin diaqnostikası"
[7] "Bakterioloji müayinə"                  "Genetik analizlər"
```